# WPF Bind to object (non static) method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to bind to an instance method of an object but I can only find examples to bind to properties or static methods. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="identifier" MethodName="getIdentifier" ObjectType="{x:Type self:PartModel}" />
</Window.Resources>

<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding identifier}" Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

`PartModel` is an object that I use for filling the ItemsControl. The `Title` shows up and the `getIdentifier` method works when I call it in my regular code. But in my View only the title shows and the column for the identifier remains empty.

Is this even possible or do I have to write the identifier to a property of the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently binding to an `identifier` property, which does not exist on the DataContext object of your list items.

Set the binding `Source` object instead, to the ObjectDataProvider resource that is references by the `identifier` resource key:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource identifier}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I tried that already, I'll have to try again later. Doesn't `StaticResource` bind to a static method of a class?

Comment: No, StaticResource doesn't even bind to anything. It just references a resource by its key (here the Source object of a Binding). It's called static (in contrast to DynamicResource) because resource lookup is done once at load time.

Comment: Hm, it didn't work with StaticResource. I ended up just adding a property called `Identifier` to my object and created a getter like `public string Identifier { get { return this.getIdentifier(); } }`. I'm marking your answer as the answer anyway, thanks for helping.

Comment: Well, I've successfully tested this with exactly your ObjectDataProvider and a class PartModel with a `public string getIdentifier()` method. Perhaps your misunderstanding is that ObjectDataProvider creates a single new PartModel instance, whereas you want to access the PartModel instances in the Items collection of your ItemsControl.